# Wikicodes? A place where anybody can view and edit code?

Tags: c++, python, algorithm, implementation, wiki

Is there a website that allows anybody to view and edit implementations (in Python, C++, etc.) of algorithms?

For example, there is a page called Pascal's Triangle. The content below shows the code of how to implement Pascal's Triangle in Python. It also shows the output when the function has a parameter of 5.

Console:

```
>>> pascal_triangle(5)
[1]
[1, 1]
[1, 2, 1]
[1, 3, 3, 1]
[1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
```

Comment: Have a look at [literateprograms.org](http://en.literateprograms.org/LiteratePrograms:Welcome). It might be what you are looking for.

Comment: It's rather unclear what you're looking for in my opinion. Are you trying to find a website with a web-based version control repository, with discussion facilities and a web-based IDE? For free? If so, I doubt the value of this question, especially here.  (Hence my original comment suggesting Google being more appropriate for this)

Comment: Please don't cross-post. Flag for a moderator to evaluate your question for migration to another site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, since this isn't a programming question, but no flagging. Still, in answer to your question, a possible site that might suit your purposes would be [algorithmist](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Main_Page)? It's pretty useful, but it has a focus on C++ and C if I recall correctly. I'm not sure how many pages have implementations on them -- many of the pages also focus on UVa problems and have implementations that solve problems, rather than being purely algorithmic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute code, too, try [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/).